# How to hand over the List of options for a ng-bootstrap typeahead

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular5, typeahead, ng-bootstrap

I want to implement a typeahead of ng-bootstrap for a lot of my inputs. Can I somehow hand in the array of options?

The problem is, that the ngbTypeahead expects a function with one parameter to be handed in like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search"/>
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
```

I need to change that so I can also hand in the array of options.
How would I do that?

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search(observable, options)"/>
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
```

Comment: maybe just past it as an object `[ngbTypeahead]="search({ observable, options })"` and then handle it in the search method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I created another function that returns the search function, which is still expecting exactly one parameter:

```
typeAheadResultFunction(hc: HeaderColumn): (text: Observable<string>) => Observable<string[]>{
    return (text$: Observable<string>) => text$ ...
}
```